# Why can't I vlookup this static reference on a sheet with a variable lookup range using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

What is wrong with the syntax of this formula? The syntax with the quoted reference within quotes seems right to me. Do the single quotes need any special treatment? Is the variable within the quotes handled correctly?

I expected a vlookup to be inserted, looking up the word "Total" in a hybrid static / variable lookup range on another sheet on our sharepoint drive.
Instead I get a run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(""Total"",'https://bingocloud.sharepoint.com/Shared Documents/Finance/Budget & Forecast/2023/2023 Forecast/2023-12 Forecast/Major Gifts/[" & VarCellValue5 & ".xlsx]Individuals'!$A:$H,8,0)"
```

Comment: You are inserting a formula that uses the A1 notation using the property that expects the R1C1 notation?

Comment: Btw, it's good practice to `Debug.Print` the formula first and inspect the output in the Immediate Window carefully.

Comment: ughhh.. thanks GSerg, works perfectly without the R1C1 notation. BigBen, glad to see you are still knocking VBA comments out of the park. I'm afraid I couldn't think of how to refer to this formula to send it to the immediate window. Can I ask for your wisdom there?

Comment: Replace `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ` with `Debug.Print` :-)